# Date is not refreshing based on the Combo value in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a `SSRS report` with following fields:

```
1. Season.
2. Start Date
3. End Date
```

Whenever season changes, the default date for `start-date` and `end-date` needs to be changed. I created a dataset which populate `start-date` and `end-date` values based on the `season` input and assigned the values to `Startdate` and `enddate` `parameters`. In Report, when `season` selected for first time `default-date` has changed correctly. But when I change the Season to another value, `default-date` are not refreshing. What is the problem here?

I have attached the screenshots below. Could someone help me on this?

First Screen-shot shows the default dates for Season 1 (Tax season)

[image]

Second Screen-shot shows the default dates for Season 2 (Pre-season) (After Changing Season-1 to Season-2 default date values are not changing )

I found out this issue occurs because the call to data-set is not happened in the second refresh.

[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: how are you assigning the default values to those parameters?

Comment: I am using a data-set to populate the date-values and assign those values into default value of parameters.  (Using get values from query option)

Comment: what datatype are the columns that you are using for the default values?

Comment: start-date and end-date columns are having datetime datatype

Comment: can you try converting them to `DATE` instead?, and can you post the query that you are using to get those values?

Comment: There is no provision for Date in ssrs parameter Datatypes. Only date/time is there.   my query is a simple select from the table based on season  "SELECT start-date, end-date FROM Table 
               WHERE Season = @Season"

Comment: I meant that you convert them to date in your query

Comment: yeah done it. but no changes

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the properties window of your Week St Date parameter?   From what you describe, it should work, so you must be making a mistake somewhere that you have left out of the description.

Comment: Are you sure that the values that you are giving to your season parameter brings results from that table?

Comment: yeah sure. when i launch the report it is working right? second refresh is the problem. but i couldn't able to take profiler trace for that screen refresh

Answer (score 1):

Your dataset for the dates has to include

```
SELECT start-date, end-date FROM Table 
WHERE Season = @Season
```

then Default the values for the date parameters to select from the dataset and it will change them when ever you change the season.

Comment: I have already done this but it is not working. I mean values are changing in back-end. But in report-screen, the changed values are not reflecting